# Germination of Bassia/Kochia scoparia (burning bush)

Tags: germination

Does anyone have any successful methods for germinating these seeds? I've tried soaking and keeping them warm, wet, dry, on the surface, buried and I've never yet managed to get them to germinate (even with different seed packets bought).

also I'm aware they're invasive pest plants in some regions, but they're fine to grow here apparently.

Answer (score 4):

They should be sown onto seed and cutting compost, scattered on the surface, and not covered with more compost. They need gentle heat to germinate, and the compost should be damp but not wet. Covering the tray you're germinating them in can help - this should be a cover that lets light through, so a clear plastic cover of some sort, but the gentle heat is the most important thing.